# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from JSONKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, jsonkit

I keep running into EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling `[obj JSONString]` method in the following code and I don't know why. I have tried turning on Zombie Objects but nothing different happens.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *obj = @{
        @"id": @1,
        @"date": @"11/07/2012",
        @"companyInfo": @"Company Details",
        @"customerInfo": @"Customer Details",
        @"taxRate": @0
    };
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    NSLog(@"%@", [obj JSONString]);

    // Other stuff here
}
```

I am running Lion. I have just upgraded to Xcode 4.4 and am using CocoaPods 0.9.2 to install JSONKit. I have tried both the `1.4` and `1.5pre` versions of JSONKit to no avail.

I am using the latest OS X SDK (10.8) with a deployment target of 10.6 (it must deploy to 10.6). I have also tried the 10.7 SDK but the results are the same. The 10.6 SDK is no longer available so I cannot test that.

`clang --version` shows:

```
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

The application compiled and ran correctly when I was using Xcode 4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was that CocoaPods does not remove the existing JSONKit files when running `pod install`. I'm using version `1.5pre` and the code executes correctly.